# Allow user to only change their own password/details

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django and have been experimenting with the Django Admin.

I can see how a superuser can give other users permissions with certain pages, for example, [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html) teaches you how to allow users to only have the ability to edit authors, not add them. However, I am having trouble giving users the ability to change their own details, but not **All** users' details.

The options in the permissions list are as follows:

```
admin | log entry | Can add log entry
admin | log entry | Can change log entry
admin | log entry | Can delete log entry
auth | group | Can add group
auth | group | Can change group
auth | group | Can delete group
auth | permission | Can add permission</option>
auth | permission | Can change permission
auth | permission | Can delete permission
auth | user | Can add user
auth | user | Can change user
auth | user | Can delete user
books | author | Can add author
books | author | Can change author
books | author | Can delete author
books | book | Can add book
books | book | Can change book
books | book | Can delete book
books | publisher | Can add publisher
books | publisher | Can change publisher
books | publisher | Can delete publisher
contenttypes | content type | Can add content type
contenttypes | content type | Can change content type
contenttypes | content type | Can delete content type
sessions | session | Can add session
sessions | session | Can change session
sessions | session | Can delete session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django admin is not suitable for normal users. If they have admin access, they can change their own password at `/admin/password_change/`. If they're not admins, you will have to write your own view that let's them change their password. Make sure to never do `user.password = new_password` but always use `user.set_password(new_password)` so it gets properly hashed.

Comment: Oh yeah I see the "Change password" link at the top-right of the screen now. Thanks a lot.